# Insert list-item in ul by jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to insert some list-items filled with content from JSON in an ul-item, but I can't get it right and I don't see what I'm doing wrong.

This is the code I'm using:

```
var over_slide = $('<div id="slider" class="slider"></div>');

over_slide.append('<ul class="orslider">');

$.each(jsonobject, function (index, d) {
    if (d.category_id == 5) {
        over_slide.append("<li><h1 class='cufon'>" + d.naam + "</h1><h2 class='cufon'>" + d.subtekst + "</h2><p>" + d.tekst + "</p></li>");
    }
});

over_slide.append('</ul>');
```

When I look into my source when I visit the page, it has an empty ul with the right classname and all list-items are placed outside the ul. How can I fix this? I have tried a lot, but it's still not working.

Comment: Can you show `jsonobject`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generated `li` and its content are being appended to the `div` instead of the `li`.

```
var over_slide = $('<div id="slider" class="slider"></div>');

var ul = $('<ul/>', {"class":"orslider"};  //create new ul object

$.each(jsonobject, function(index, d){    
     if(d.category_id == 5){
         //append elements to the ul instead of the div
         ul.append("<li><h1 class='cufon'>"+d.naam+"</h1><h2 class='cufon'>"+d.subtekst+"</h2><p>"+d.tekst+"</p></li>"); 
     }
});
over_slide.append(ul);
//at somepoint over_slide needs to be appended to the DOM
```

**For better performance**

```
var over_slide = $('<div id="slider" class="slider"></div>');

var ul = $('<ul/>', {"class":"orslider"};  //create new ul object
var html = "";
$.each(jsonobject, function(index, d){    
     if(d.category_id == 5){
         //append elements to var
         html += "<li><h1 class='cufon'>"+d.naam+"</h1><h2 class='cufon'>"+d.subtekst+"</h2><p>"+d.tekst+"</p></li>"; 
     }
});

//only perform append once
ul.append(html);

over_slide.append(ul);
//at somepoint over_slide needs to be appended to the DOM
```

Comment: @MarcoBinnekamp Glad I could help.  If you want this function to perform better, gather the li markup in a string inside the loop, then call the `ul.append` outside of the loop.

Comment: You need to accept the answer, not edit the question as "solved".